# Unable to import more than one level of module

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm working on a browser app and am using the below method to import modules as needed. Unfortunately any modules imported at the 'second level' or deeper treat the asterisk '*' as an unexpected token. It's been a few years since my last JavaScript work and am unsure what I'm doing wrong as much has changed and is new to me.

Below is a minimum example that encounters the issue. The structure of each module is to emulate C# classes with public, private, and static objects and almost entirely remove the need to type 'this.' over and over and over again as is the .js way of doing things.

Content.js

```
//Directly attached to the page using <script type="module" src="Content.js"></script>

import * as XRVideo from "../Viewer/Scripts/XRVideo.js"; //This works perfectly

var urlA = "Testing/VideoA.mp4";
var urlB = "Testing/VideoB.mp4";

var arrXRVideos = [];

window.addEventListener("load", (e) =>{
    arrXRVideos.Push(XRVideo.New(urlA));
    arrXRVideos.Push(XRVideo.New(urlB));
});
```

XRVideo.js

```
import * as XRScene from "./Core/XRScene.js"; //This throws an Unexpected Token '*' Error
import * as XRSkybox from "./Core/XRSkybox.js";


/* Static */
export const XRStatus = {
    Stopped : 0,
};


/* Instanced */
export function New(videoURL){
    var _isInitialized = false;
    var _url = "";

//#region Pseudo Constructor
    {
        _url = videoUrl;

        _isInitialized = true;
    }
//#endregion

    /* Getters & Setters */
    function GetURL(){
        return _url;
    }

    /* Exposed As Public */
    //Properties can't be directly exposed otherwise they become static...
    return{
        GetURL : GetURL
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using classes, rather than the attempt at a constructor function?

Comment: Try import XRScene from "./Core/XRScene.js"; because it may  just have a default export

Comment: @Heretic Because there's no class level variables in ES6 without defining them as this.variableName  in the constructor. Additionally ES6 classes force you to have to use 'This.' all the time. In my last class I had over 100 instances of this.MehtodName or this.PropertyName, etc. It's madness. Run a CTFL + F on https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-samples/blob/ebcec741aaf0e8bc54cf9271d428c8905cb99110/js/render/core/node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was due to a broken line comment throwing off the system. Always look at the previous line for 'Unexpected' errors...

I didn't notice this due to how VS Code's Default theme, visually styles code comments and hyperlinks the same. Specifically both lines look like the same green text despite one being a comment and the other not.

```
//This is a comment, VS Code shows it as a dirty green.
//I am a code comment

//This is a URL that accidentally didn't get the '//' to turn it into a comment,
//VS Code shows it as a dirty green making it look like a comment.
https://github.com/blah-blah-blah

import * as Bah from "./Foo.js"; //Unexpected token '*'
```